# SSL Certificate error while running python -m nltk.downloader -d $NLTK_DATA punkt command on aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, nltk, aws-codestar

Getting SSL Certificate error while deploying the following code on aws lambda using aws codestar build pipeline.

Looked at multiple community discussions, nothing worked out.

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    commands:

      # Upgrade AWS CLI & PIP to the latest version
      - pip install --upgrade awscli
      - pip install --upgrade pip

      # Define Directories
      - export HOME_DIR=`pwd`
      - export NLTK_DATA=$HOME_DIR/nltk_data

  pre_build:
    commands:
      - cd $HOME_DIR

      # Create VirtualEnv to package for lambda
      - virtualenv venv
      - . venv/bin/activate

      # Install Supporting Libraries
      - pip install -U scikit-learn
      - pip install -U requests

      # Install WordNet
      - pip install -U nltk
      - python -m nltk.downloader -d $NLTK_DATA punkt

      # Output Requirements
      - pip freeze > requirements.txt

      # Discover and run unit tests in the 'tests' directory. For more information, see <https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#test-discovery>
      - python -m unittest discover tests

  build:
    commands:
      - cd $HOME_DIR
      - mv $VIRTUAL_ENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/* .
```

Answer (score 0):

Only way that worked for me was download the modules and install them into my source folder in a nltk_data folder then create a lambda environment variable NLTK with value ./nltk_data